# how to listen to notifications when the app is closed in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to develop an application that keeps listening for the notifications such as sms, email etc. I could do this with the application put into background. But I want to do the same even when it is CLOSED?

Any suggestions and tips please?

Comment: I mean, I want to have an application that listens to notifications even when it is closed (when user extis from the app). I know this is possible when the app is running in background but how to do this when the application is not active even in the background i.e. a complete exit?

Comment: I think you don't understand how the BlackBerry OS works. What you're asking is both impossible, and not necessary. A properly written background application has no significant disadvantage, performance or memory wise, than an exited application that would have to save enough state to respond to an event.

Comment: Thanks Richard, it's true that an exited application differs little from that of a background app. Well, what we are trying to do is something similar to J2ME's PushRegistry. BTW, it's the requirement that demands us do it this way :(

Comment: I assume you are talking about the newer Push API registry that allows the program to exit. The catch there is that the Push framework is still running. Unless you can leverage some other "always up" application to launch your application the way the Push framework does, the best you could do is write a small always running application that then launches the main application. In the end this is no different (but more error prone) than just having one application spool down and leave the listeners registered.

Comment: Got that Richard. We have done the application by putting it into background instead of exiting. All went well in the end. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. It is never easy when requirements clash with the OS design.

Comment: use a background service that will run in background. Use alternate entry point.